# What are name and other examples for the type of break/tempo change near the end of "Be our guest"

Tags: melody, musical-forms

My 5 year old daughter is obsessed with the new (2017) version of "Beauty and the Beast" and we are listening to the music non stop for weeks and albeit being a musical grouch it really grew on me.

One thing keeps nagging on me though and drives me insane. In the quiet fantastic "Be our guest" even I get a lot of influences from older Big Band Jazz and Broadway tunes. There is one particular sequence near the end of the song where after a chorus crescendo(?) the tempo suddenly winds down and then immediately start rising again with very punctuated vocal and orchestra strikes. Here you can hear the exact piece in question:

I'm absolutely sure I have heard this type of break many times before but I can't find another instance nor do I really know what to look for.

After this long explanation here my actual question. Has this musical construct a name? What are other (famous) songs that use it? In addition I would be thankful for pointers to other musical reference in this song.

Comment: I feel like I've heard that in the Simpsons. Maybe a **Ritardando** followed by an **Accelerando**? Don't know an actual name for the break, but I also feel I heard a quick Perfect Authentic Cadence as well. I'm thinking out loud here

Comment: I don't know the answer. But it is nice to hear some real music featured in contemporary entertainment. +1

Answer (score 1):

It's for a big kick line finale. Here's an example with choreo:

(The kick line starts at about 3:10)

The score actually calls for a more dramatic slowdown (and speed up afterwards) than they did in the original Broadway run.